# NumLock turns off when switching layouts, how can I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, numlock

It looks like I have a bug in 16.04; when I switch keyboard layouts, NumLock is turned off. How  to fix this?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my english.

Comment: No need to excuse!

Comment: What other layouts do you use?

Comment: I use english and russian layouts.

Comment: Are you using external keyboards? Are you using keyboard shortcuts to switch? Which desktop environment are you using? Edit the question to include these info.